# pandaboard, robotino dependencies problem

Tags: ros, robotino, pandaboard, dependencies, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,
i'm trying to install the robotino stack on a pandaboardES.

At first i installed ROS groovy (bare bones) following the guide for groovy on pandaboard
--> roscore starts succesfully

now i am trying to build the robotino stack, but i have problems with missing dependencies.

a few packages are build with calling

```
$roscd robotino_node
$rosmake --pre-clean
```

but at first the "geometry_msgs" packages was missing.
after downloading and building robotino_node for the second time, another package was missing. like this i downloaded and built the following stacks:

- geometry_msgs
- geometry
- image_transport
- pluginlib
- class_loader

Now, "console_bridge" is missing, but i can't find it on ros.org.

Is there a possibility to install all missing dependencies automatically?
Where can i find "console_bridge?
Am i doing anything in principle wrong!?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53151/pandaboard,-robotino-dependencies-problem/) by [uwlau](https://answers.ros.org/users/4031/uwlau/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-01-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As far as I know there is no possibility to install all missing dependencies on an ARM platform, so you will either have to add all missing packages by hand or install the desktop package and not the bare bone.
Here is what I found to be the easiest approach:

Set up a catkin workspace with the desktop package. Remove the big packages if you know you will not need them. This would be packages like collada, opencv and PCL.

Now catkin_make everything, fixing occurring errors. This will take a considerable amount of time.

Set up a rosbuild workspace and with a link to the catkin install folder.

```
rosws init . /ros/install/folder
```

Install your stack here.

Edit: If you are missing console_bridge, I would assume you did not link your rosbuild workspace to the install folder.

---

Originally posted by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) with karma: 1554 on 2013-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello uwlau

like you I installed first the barebone groovy (ros_comm) but it is also possible to use (robot) if you delete some packages by hand. The robot package includes the messages and also the console_bridge you need and it will work under PandaBoard with its armhf architecture!

I used the Raspbian tutorial at:

h++p://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/Raspbian/Source

and modifed it for the PandaBoard:

h++p://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/PandaBoard/Source

follow the steps and install the "robot" and not the "ros_comm".

Then also create a seperate workspace like kalectro said but you will find these steps also in the tutorial.

I think this will solve your problem.

---

Originally posted by [zumili](https://answers.ros.org/users/3935/zumili/) with karma: 141 on 2013-01-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1